# NodeJS: Check Machines OS while in Linux Bash on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, linux, windows

I need to exec a binary depending on the OS.

My Machine is a windows 10 System with an Ubuntu subsystem. 
When i try to get the OS with `process.platform` my console tells me I'm using Linux.

I have the binaries for Windows and for Linux and I want to run my .exe if the current machine is Windows, but how can I get the OS, when `process.plattform` returns Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a module, which provides a number of operating system specific utility methods.

In Windows 10 my code is:

```
var os = require('os');

console.log(os.type()); 
console.log(os.release()); 
console.log(os.platform());
```

Comment: My returns to your snippet is:
Linux

4.4.0-43-Microsoft

linux

It looks like I can use os.release() to get the windows Information.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
let OS = os.release();
if(OS.indexOf("Microsoft")>=0){
    bin = bin.concat(".exe");
}
```

Thank you javatar.